# BigQuery Scheduled queries only on working days

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, cloud

I need a scheduled query only between Monday to Friday between 9 and 7 o'clock:

Scheduled queries is currently: every hour from 9:00 to 19:00

But how to modify for Mo-Fr ?

- every monday to friday from 9:00 to 19:00 not working
- every monday from 9:00 to 19:00 working (so day of the week is in general not working ?)

Thanks

Comment: Did you consider using Cloud Scheduler?

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: The question at hand is much more complex than the Custom setting in BigQuery Scheduled Queries allows. For this purpose, @guillaume blaquiere has the best suggestion: use [Cloud Scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/schedule-run-cron-job) to run a cron job. Tools like Crontab Guru can be helpful in creating a statement such as [00 9-19 * * 1-5](https://crontab.guru/#00_9-19_*_*_1-5).

For simpler Scheduled Queries, please review the following from the official documentation: [Set up scheduled queries](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/scheduling-queries#set_up_scheduled_queries).

Specifically,

> To specify a custom frequency, select Custom, then enter a Cron-like
> time specification in the Custom schedule field; for example every 3
> hours.

There is [excellent documentation in the Custom Interval tab here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/scheduling-jobs-with-cron-yaml?&_ga=2.75834579.-736750696.1641841337#formatting_the_schedule) on the many options you have available in this field.